# Google Maps Android

Tags: google-maps

I recently completed an android project for google maps. It's an app that performs distance calculation named Android Taxi Meter.

I followed all the rules to get api v2 for maps and did all jobs perfectly. Now the problem is that I have some starting screens splash, login, language, info, and finally in last map activity which is actually calculating the distance between two places entered by customer. When I run this project as a whole it does not show map on it.

But when I just separated the map activity as a separate project it works. I'm now confused, what is the matter? A separate map activity is working properly but with other starting activities it doesn't show the map, while the rest of project works normally.

Comment: may be your passing parameters mistakes .......... check it once

Comment: attach jsfiddle link also

Comment: everything is same in both projects,, separate map activity and complete project including map activity but the problem is still there..

Comment: See the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start). It sounds like you generated your key using the debug certificate. Make sure you use the release one instead.

Comment: give a proper link to follow all necessary steps because i followed all steps.. but problem is still there..

Comment: does the code show up somewhere